# DataDog Log Search empty string facet

Tags: datadog

On DataDog log search, I want to search for logs with empty string for a specific facet, e.g. logs with userId is empty. `@userId:''` , `@userId:""`, `-@userId:*` non worked.

Answer (score 23):

this seem to be working:
`-@userId:*?*` do not forget the minus at the start.

Comment: For future searchers: I was hoping to use this to find instances of my array facet where the array is null/empty, but no luck. thanks for sharing anyway, what a strange wrinkle!

Answer (score 9):

This may have been patched. `-@userId:*` is working for me, now.

Comment: This didn't work. @hevi's solution did